# How can I control the output level from a HV (220VDC) floating regulator using a DAC?

Tags: power-supply, power, high-voltage, linear-regulator

I have a 240V DC supply I want to clean up and make adjustable (150-220V) with an LR8 high voltage floating regulator.

I can't use the standard way of connecting the DAC to the adjust pin (current summing junction) of the the LR8 with a series resistor as the voltage is too high - the adjust pin is only 1.2V under the 220V output voltage means a DAC will not have a long life.

Could I use a MOSFET with a gate driven by a DAC to its linear region as below to set the voltage?

Thanks!

EDIT: All of the resistor values are approximate and should be taken with a handful of salt.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUfGS.png

[image]

Comment: This kind of project sounds chock full of pitfalls and exciting and dangerous failure modes.  That said I wonder if something like a PWM signal optocoupled up to a smoothing filter floating with the output could work.

Comment: Hm, that's an idea. How about a linear optocoupler (like the LOC110). I've never used one so I'd have to look into the servo mechanism of the photodiodes.

Comment: Since you need a DAC somewhere anyway, I'd run the optocoupler PWM so you don't have to worry about linearity and filter it on the far side.

Comment: So something like this (I think that's where the filter cap would go): https://i.imgur.com/zwKV3CI.png
Although I'm not sure how that would be better than my original idea but also PWM'd with a filter cap.